# How to inject React Component inside WebView (react-native-webview)?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-webview

Is there a way to pass in a web React component to WebView directly? Something like this-

```
import ReactContainer from 'somewhere';
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";

<WebView
        source={{ html: "<ReactContainer/>" }}
></WebView>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can render a React component to its initial HTML with `renderToString()` and then display it inside your WebView like so:

```js
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'
import ReactContainer from 'somewhere';
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";

<WebView source={{ html: renderToString(<ReactContainer />) }}></WebView>;
```

More infos about ReactDOMServer [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html).

Comment: Thanks @rémi-doreau this does render the react component .. following to the above approach you suggested..if the react component inside uses document object and appends a script..how will this gonna work? Do you have any idea ? As document object will not be available for react-native app.

Comment: Is it possible to pass props to the `<ReactContainer />`?

Comment: Did you manage to do it with complex react components? that receive props, uses state management, etc?
I'm facing the same issue with the need of loading a big and complex sub-tree of a bigger react component
@Trevor

Comment: Please if any one finds solution give me a suggestion  
I had try this, but I got error "Property 'TextEncoder' doesn't exist, js engine: hermes" & " Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder"  and "A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes"

Answer (score -1):

if you want to load HTML directly, you can use the html property in WebView’s source property, as shown below:

```
<WebView
  originWhitelist={['*']}
  source={{ html: '<h1>Hello world</h1>' }}
/>
```

for more details of react-native-web-view you can learn from here

https://blog.logrocket.com/the-complete-guide-to-react-native-webview/

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md

Answer (score -1):

No, there is not. React.js and React native shares the same syntax but are really different framework: they follow different rules and are build in a different way.
Inside a webview, there is no react framework avaiable or runtime (unless you import React.js as a `<script>` tag as a website would).

However, as some other answer pointed, you can use `renderToString()` and it will work in some situations (it just precompile your component, it does not provide exactly what you want) - it's more a hack than a solution.